# SOAP request format in objective c

Tags: objective-c, soap, syntax-error

Maybe this is a very easy question but i didn't figure it out. What is the correct version of this?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
 "<soap:Envelope 
 xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
 xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
 xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
 "<soap:Body>"
 "<GetQuote 
 xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">"
 "<symbol>%@</symbol>"
 "</GetQuote>"
 "</soap:Body>"
 "</soap:Envelope>",
 textBox.text
 ];
```

Comment: There is a syntax error at string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it by below way:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:
      @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
      "<soap:Envelope "
      "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\""
      "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
      "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
      "<soap:Body>"
      "<GetQuote "
      "xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">"
      "<symbol>%@</symbol>"
      "</GetQuote>"
      "</soap:Body>"
      "</soap:Envelope>",
      textBox.text
      ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
 <soap:Envelope 
 xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
 xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
 xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
 <soap:Body>
 <GetQuote 
 xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">
 <symbol>%@</symbol>
 </GetQuote>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>",
 textBox.text
 ];
```

Comment: I found the correct version and i will post it 7-8 hours later.